# intent.getIntExtra( AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, appwidgetprovider

I cant get the id of the clicked widget in onReceive(). Always return 0. Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(WIDGET_BUTTON)) {
            int widgetId = intent.getIntExtra( AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID); 

            log("WID ID" + widgetId);
```

I take the code form the Android Developers Docs, i dont know why it isnt working..

---

**THE ANSWER:**

I miss:

```
AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
```

So my code goes like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_main);




    if (intent.getAction().equals(WIDGET_BUTTON)) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();     
        int widgetId = 0;

        if (extras != null && extras.containsKey(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID)) 
            widgetId = intent.getIntExtra(mgr.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID); 
            log("1 - WID ID" + widgetId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) says INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID == 0, so you're receiving Intents that don't have an EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID extra.

Are you adding that extra when creating the Intent?